# Jquery MIME Error in Console Not Returning Enough Data

Tags: javascript, jquery, webapi

I am trying to use api that is returning json data and I keep getting this error in the console: "was loaded even though its MIME type (“text/plain”) is not a valid JavaScript MIME type." I clicked on the MSDN website link next to the error but I don't understand how to fix it. I also read some similar questions posted on SO and tried adding text/javascript like someone said but it's still not fixing my issue. Here is my script to link jquery:

My page used to return a couple lines of data from the api but I'm not sure what I changed now I just get one line back and this error in the console. Is there anyway to fix this erorr?

Comment: Are you positively sure that message comes from the JSON response? It just seems that the server where JavaScript code is loaded from is declaring *.js files to be plain text. Also, what do you mean with "Not Returning Enough Data"? Is that the same issue or you're asking two questions?

Comment: This is the script tag I'm using <script  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"  
 integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="   
 crossorigin="anonymous"></script> and I get that error for this script tag. I'n not sure what I need to change in this tag to fix the error @ÁlvaroGonzález

Comment: I'm trying to get some data from the api but the data is not working so I think the problem may be with my jquery script tag @ÁlvaroGonzález

Comment: It isn't an error, it's a warning (please note the "was loaded even though" part) and there's nothing the browser can do to change server-side settings (but it can ignore them, as it's actually doing). If your code is not even running, the issue must be somewhere else. But I really feel you're asking several several things at the same time. Please focus in problems one by one.